# State space representation of a 2 tank system

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, modeling

I am figuring out the state space equations of a connected 2-tank system. For the 1st tank, the state space equation is as follows :
`dh̃₁/dt = (-K₁/ρA₁) h̃₁ + (1/ρA₁) m̃ᵢ` where h̃₁= h - h̄, m̃ᵢ = m - m̄ and K₁ = (k/2√h̄).
No problems here. Perfectly clear. What is tripping me up is the equation for the 2nd tank.

First, I do a mass balance.
$$ρA₂dh₂/dt = k√h₁ - k√h₂$$
Then we perform linearization using the Taylor series expansion and ignore the terms with the 2nd derivative and higher.
So, we get `ρA₂dh₂/dt = (k√ħ₁) + (k/2√ħ₁) (h₁ - ħ₁) - (k√ħ₂) - (k/2√ħ₂)(h₂ - h̅₂)`

Next, we get
`ρA₂dh₂/dt = (k/2√ħ₁) (h̃₁)- (k/2√ħ₂)(h̃₂)`

My question is simple, what happened to the k√ħ₁ and - (k√ħ₂) terms which were there earlier?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They got cancelled.

At equilibrium when $dh₂/dt = 0$, the equation for the second tank is $0 = k√ħ₁ - k√ħ₂$.